# Format HTML Table header

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to format a table to look like this...

Basically i want the "Dates" row  to have two columns inside it (to and from) both of them 50% the width of dates...but however when i try to format it. "To" takes all of date and "From" takes all of Name. they arent locked under "Dates"

Any help will be appreciated...Thank you[image]

```
                    <th width="100%">Dates</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th>
         <tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">To</td>
    <td width="50%">From</td>
  </tr>

</tr>
```

Change

```
  <table border="1">
                      <tr class="heading"> <td colspan="6">Information</td> </tr >
                   <th width ="15" colspan="2">Dates</th><th> Name</th><th>Age</th>
         <tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="2">From</td>
    <td width="2">To</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width="5">
  <input type="text" class="input" name="1fdate" /></td>
     <td width="2">
  <input type="text" class="input" name="1fdate" /></td>

  </tr>


</tr>




                    </table>
```

Comment: Can you show more data? You may need to make to/from `<th>` too and use the headers attribute as well as what Back suggests so that the table is accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you need. You use `colspan` and `rowspan` to merge the cells. When you set `colspan` to "2" in Date cell, it spans the row with two cells (or colums). And you set also `rowspan` of the cells next to Date to "2" so that they will span the rows taken by whole Date section.

```
<table width="600" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th width="200" colspan="2" scope="col">Date</th>
    <th width="200" rowspan="2" scope="col">Name</th>
    <th width="200" rowspan="2" scope="col">Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th width="100">To</th>
    <th width="100">From</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yes that is good...perfect even...but when i replace a &nbsp with 
<input type="text" class="input" name="1fdate" />
It stretches it...far wider than i want and setting the width
 <td width="5">
  <input type="text" class="input" name="1fdate" /></td>
 doesnt fix it or make it smaller

Comment: @kemnet In the cell <td width="100"></td>, <input size="14" /> fits very well. Note that these numbers are not the same unit. So you might use CSS, which is better. So <td style="width:100px;"></td> and <input style="width:100px;" /> fit perfectly. No need to deal with width and size anymore! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<th width="100%">Dates</th>
```

to have `colspan` value. Like

```
<th colspan="2">Dates</th>
```

Comment: <th width="2">Dates</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th>
         <tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="5%">To</td>
    <td width="5%">From</td>
  </tr>

</tr>

Comment: This made it a little better...Thanks

Comment: I have a problem thou... i added this new inputs "refer to the orginal question" and the "too" and "from" column have gotten quite large...and is not responding to my width formatting to shorten them

Answer (score 0):

Replace first line with below

```
                <th width="100%" colspan="2">Dates</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th>
```